# react native with tenstack, when submitting the mutatuion function nothing happe?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hook-form, react-query

im trying to submit a form but nothing happen the button is changed to chargement state because of the isLoading = true, but nothing happend after that .
**the server is working fine i have test it with postman... and when i run an android similator it work fine but whene i try ios device after scaning the qr code from windows pc this problem happend ?**
here is the code :

**here is the signup component:**

```
    import { Alert, Platform, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { defaultStyles } from '@/constants/Styles';
import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { signUpType, signUpSchema } from '@/utils/types';
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';
import { z } from 'zod';
import axios, { AxiosError } from 'axios';
import { API_URL } from '@/constants';
import { useMutation } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import useAuthStore from '@/utils/zustandStore/authStore';
import Colors from '@/constants/Colors';
import { signUp } from '@/services/authServices/signUpService';

/* 
    * sign up component to create user account
    * using the react-hook-form to handle the form value
    * using tenstack-query to handel the api request for the signing up user
    * updating the storage data
*/

// * creating the props type for signUp component
type signUpPropsType = {
    setAuthMode: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<"signup" | "login">>
}

const config = {
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
}

const SignUp = ({ setAuthMode }: signUpPropsType) => {
    // * dispatching the setAuth from the authStore
    const setAuth = useAuthStore(store => store.setAuth)
    // * initializing react-hook-form
    const { control, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm<signUpType>({ resolver: zodResolver(signUpSchema) })
    // * handling the POST request to create new user
    const { mutateAsync: signUpUser, data: returnedData, isPending: isLoading, reset, error } = useMutation({
        mutationKey: ['signUpUser'],
        mutationFn: async (user: signUpType) => {
            console.log('running mutation')
            console.log(user)
            return await signUp(API_URL, user)
        }
    })

    // * handling errors on submission
    const onInvalid = () => {
        console.log('error: ')
        console.log(error)
    }

    // * handling the submit action
    const onsubmit = (user: signUpType) => {
        console.log('start submitting')
        // * running the mutationFN 
        signUpUser(user, {
            // * when the submit action is successful
            onSuccess(returnedData, variables, context) {
                console.log("returnedData")
                console.log(returnedData)
                console.log("variables")
                console.log(variables)
                console.log("context")
                console.log(context)
                setAuth(null, 'signIn')
                // * switching the authMode to login to let the user login to the application
                Alert.alert('Action Terminée', '', [
                    { text: 'OK' },
                ]);
                // * clean up
                reset()
            },
            // * when the submit action fails
            onError: (error) => {
                // * checking if the error is coming from zod
                if (error instanceof z.ZodError) {
                    Alert.alert('Error', error.message, [
                        { text: 'OK' },
                    ]);
                }
                else if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
                    if (error.response?.data.message === "le mot de passe doit commencer par une lettre majuscule et contenir au moins un chiffre et un caractère spécifique") {
                        return null
                    }
                    // * display the response error message
                    Alert.alert('Error', error.response?.data.message, [
                        { text: 'OK' },
                    ]);
                }
                else {
                    // * display the error message
                    Alert.alert('Error', error.message, [
                        { text: 'OK' },
                    ]);
                }
            }
        })
    }
    // const fakeSignUp = () => {
    //     setAuth(null, 'signIn')

    //     Alert.alert('Registration Valid', '', [
    //         { text: 'OK', onPress: () => { setAuthMode('login') } },
    //     ]);
    // }
    return <>
        <Controller
            control={control}
            render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                <TextInput
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    placeholder="Prénom..."
                    placeholderTextColor={Colors.grey}
                    style={defaultStyles.inputField}
                    onBlur={onBlur}
                    onChangeText={text => onChange(text)}
                    value={value}
                />
            )}
            name="name"
        />
        <Text style={[defaultStyles.errorsMessages, { marginBottom: 10 }]}>{errors.name?.message}</Text>
        <Controller
            control={control}
            render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                <TextInput
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    placeholder="Nom..."
                    placeholderTextColor={Colors.grey}
                    style={defaultStyles.inputField}
                    onBlur={onBlur}
                    onChangeText={text => onChange(text)}
                    value={value}
                />
            )}
            name="surname"
        />
        <Text style={[defaultStyles.errorsMessages, { marginBottom: 10 }]}>{errors.surname?.message}</Text>
        <Controller
            control={control}
            render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                <TextInput
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    placeholder="Email..."
                    placeholderTextColor={Colors.grey}
                    style={defaultStyles.inputField}
                    onBlur={onBlur}
                    onChangeText={text => onChange(text)}
                    value={value}
                />
            )}
            name="email"
        />
        <Text style={[defaultStyles.errorsMessages, { marginBottom: 10 }]}>{errors.email?.message}</Text>
        <Controller
            control={control}
            render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                <TextInput
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    placeholder="Mot de pass..."
                    placeholderTextColor={Colors.grey}
                    style={defaultStyles.inputField}
                    onBlur={onBlur}
                    onChangeText={text => onChange(text)}
                    value={value}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                />
            )}
            name="password"
        />
        <Text style={[defaultStyles.errorsMessages, { marginBottom: 10 }]}>{(error instanceof AxiosError && error.response?.data.message) ? "le mot de passe doit commencer par une lettre majuscule et contenir au moins un chiffre et un caractère spécifique" : errors.password?.message}</Text>
        <Controller
            control={control}
            render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                <TextInput
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    placeholder="Numero de telephone..."
                    placeholderTextColor={Colors.grey}
                    style={defaultStyles.inputField}
                    onBlur={onBlur}
                    onChangeText={text => onChange(text)}
                    value={value}
                    keyboardType='phone-pad'
                />
            )}
            name="phone"
        />
        <Text style={[defaultStyles.errorsMessages, { marginBottom: 10 }]}>{errors.phone?.message}</Text>

        <TouchableOpacity style={defaultStyles.btn} disabled={isLoading} onPress={handleSubmit(onsubmit)}>
            <Text style={defaultStyles.btnText}>{isLoading ? 'chargement ...' : 'Confirmer'}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </>
}

 export default SignUp
```

the signup funtion:

```
import { signUpType } from "@/utils/types";

export const signUp = (url: string, signUpData: signUpType) => fetch(`${url}/auth/signup`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    // body: JSON.stringify({
    //   firstParam: 'yourValue',
    //   secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
    // }),
    body: JSON.stringify(signUpData),
});
```

**the types:**

```
import { listingGeoData } from "@/constants/DummyData";
import { z } from "zod";


const signUpSchema = z.object({
    name: z.string(),
    surname: z.string(),
    email: z.string().email(),
    password: z.string().min(8, { message: 'le mot de pass il faut plus que 8 character' }),
    phone: z.string().length(10, { message: 'le numéro de téléphone doit contenir 10 caractères' }),
})

const logInSchema = z.object({
    email: z.string().email(),
    password: z.string(),
})

const messageSchema = z.object({
    name: z.string(),
    surname: z.string(),
    message: z.string(),
})


// the inferred type
type logInType = z.infer<typeof logInSchema>;
type signUpType = z.infer<typeof signUpSchema>;
type messageType = z.infer<typeof messageSchema>

// data type
type listingGeoDataType = typeof listingGeoData

export {
    logInSchema,
    signUpSchema,
    messageSchema,
    logInType,
    signUpType,
    messageType,
    listingGeoDataType,
}
```

**the console.log results:**

```
iOS Bundled 192ms (C:\Users\kikou\OneDrive\المستندات\ReactNative projects\algbnb\application\node_modules\expo-router\entry.js)
 LOG  start submitting
 LOG  running mutation
 LOG  {"email": "kerou@gmail.com", "name": "amram", "password": "dhdhdhhdgg", "phone": "0676178342", "surname": "kerou"}
```

**env file:**

```
EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL="http://lcoalhost:5000/api/v1"
```